# Inserting a Line at a specific place in a txt using .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file

The process I currently use to insert a string into a text file is to read the file and modify it as I write the file out again which seems to be how everyone is doing it.

Since .net has such a diverse library I was wondering if there was a specific command for inserting a string at a specific line in a txt file.

I would imagine it would look something like this:

```
dim file as file
file.open("filePath")

file.insert(string, location) 'this isn't actually an option, I tried
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's nothing specifically to do that in .NET.

You can do it very *simply* if you're happy to read all the lines of text in:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToList();
lines.Insert(location, text);
File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);
```

It would be more efficient in terms of memory to write code to copy a line at a time, inserting the new line at the right point while you copy, but that would be more work. If you *know* your file will be small, I'd go for the above.

Comment: Yeah this looks like what I'm after. mine would be a bit longer because the location varies, I would have to find the location during the reading in process.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply read all the text into a string, then use the string [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method, e.g.

```
File.WriteAllText("file.txt", File.ReadAllText("file.txt").Insert(startIndex, "value"));
```

Comment: Similar concept as the other answer, but using a list seems cleaner and allows me to do a list.contains("text") to find the location I need.

Comment: Note that list.Contains("text") will yeild true for a line that exactly matches "text", since you read all lines. That may be exactly what you need, if you need to match substrings in lines you would do something like list.Where(line => line.Contains("text")).Any()

Comment: Hah I had just discovered this, I was going to do a "For Each item in list" " if instr(item,"text") " but your way seems much shorter